# AngularJs: Getting unexpected output while assigin value in array?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying this to get 2 values to be inserted in an js array.

```
$scope.ttabs = [];

for(p = 1; p <= $scope.no_of_groups; p++) {
    $scope.ttabs[p] = [1];  
    console.log($scope.ttabs);  
}
```

the p $scope.no_of_groups is here has value 2.

Now I am getting console output as ..

```
[undefined, [1], [1]]
```

why does it showing undefined at first index?

Comment: Change for(p = 1; p <= $scope.no_of_groups; p++) { to for(p = 0; p < $scope.no_of_groups; p++) {

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you start from the index `1`. Array's index starts from the `0`. In your code you don't assign any value to the index `0`, so it will have the default value which is **undefined**.

Change you code into to start from the 0, and also remove the equal sign from the condition.

```
$scope.ttabs = [];

for(var p = 0; p < $scope.no_of_groups; p++) {
    $scope.ttabs[p] = [1];  
    console.log($scope.ttabs);  
}

console.log($scope.ttabs);
```

Output

```
[[1], [1]]
```

Comment: also `console.log($scope.ttabs); ` needs to be out of the `for` loop

Comment: but i want result start with 1 and end with 2 .. is there any solution. is there any associative array solution?

Comment: In other case you can use `{}` object with the properties names in indexes, like
a[1], a[2], but it is not a good practice l to use an object as an array. I think in your case you can manipulate with the array

Comment: i tried with the code provided by the asker....i didnt seen anything like he mentioned please check this http://plnkr.co/edit/sqr13NWZBpO9EUeaIw8G?p=preview

Comment: @SaEChowdary you are right. In Google Chrome it doesn't show the first item, but try it in Mozilla Firefox

Comment: yes your right....may i know why like this for different browsers as the code is same??

Comment: @SaEChowdary because each browser has its own JS Engine, Chrome - V8, Mozilla - Gecko

Comment: @user7192960 why do you want your array to start at index 1 instead of 0?

Answer (score 2):

```
    $scope.ttabs = [];

    for(p = 0; p <= $scope.no_of_groups; p++) {
        $scope.ttabs[p] = [1];  
        console.log($scope.ttabs);  
    }
```

Javascript array starts from 0th index
so you are getting undefined for 1st place

Answer (score 0):

Because you start p = 1, when you assign that as an index to the array, the array is allocated with length 2, since arrays are index from index 0. Since nothing is inserted into the array at index 0, that index is undefined.

```
var ar = [];
for(var i = 1;i < 2;i++){
   ar[1] = 1;
}
console.log(ar) // outputs [undefined, 1, 1]
```

while:

```
var ar = [];
for(var i = 0;i < 2;i++){
   ar[1] = 1;
}
console.log(ar) // outputs [1, 1]
```